# Realizar test unitario en Eclipse o Visual Studio

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, eclipse, test

Teniendo la siguente funcion:

```
public int Suma (int numero1, int numero2){
return numero1+numero2;
}
```

Sea en `Java` o `C#`.

Existe la forma de testear esta funcion sin tener que invocarla en el MAIN?

O sea que si yo en mi proyecto tengo varias funciones o metodos de las clases, tengo alguna forma de testearlos uno por uno (hardcodeando los parametros que yo quiera), sin tener que instanciar las clases o llamar las funciones en el cuerpo principal (main)?

Comment: si, con proyectos de test.

Comment: Lo podrias explicar mejor por favor, no entiendo a que te referis con Proyectos de test

Comment: no son iguales para c# que para java. Vas a tener que investigar sobre proyectos de test para cada lenguaje. son proyectos atachados a tu proyecto principal que ejecutan los test que vos necesitas sobre tu codigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Para hacerlo en Visual Studio 2013 o superior

***En versiones anteriores desconozco si sea el mismo proceso, pero no
debe ser muy distinto.***

1.- Debes agregar un Proyecto de Test, sobre tu solución has lo siguiente:

Clic derecho > Agregar Nuevo Proyecto > Visual C# > Pruebas > Proyecto de Prueba Unitaria

2.- Debes importar las referencias a tu Proyecto de Pruebas unitarias( pueden ser otros proyectos de tu misma solución o dlls ya compiladas también) que quieras testear.

3.- El Proyecto de Pruebas crea por default una clase similar a esta.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

    }
}
```

4.- Supongamos que tienes una clase llamada **Operaciones.cs** en otro proyecto y lo importas al Proyecto de Pruebas para testear sus metodos.

```
public class Operaciones
{
    public int Suma(int numero1, int numero2)
    {
        return numero1 + numero2;
    }
}
```

5.- Así harias un Test del metodo **Suma** en tu Proyecto de Pruebas.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using DemoUtils; /*Es la referencia del proyecto que contiene la clase 
Operaciones*/

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
  [TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
      [TestMethod]
      public void TestMethod1()
      {
        Operaciones operacion = new Operaciones();

        Assert.AreEqual(10, operacion.Suma(5, 5));        
      }
   }
}
```

En el código anterior instancias una clase de Operaciones, y con **Assert.AreEqual** le indicas que el valor del primer parámetro debe ser Igual al resultado que obtendras de tu metodo **Suma** para que se cumpla la prueba.

> Existen otros metodos de **Assert** que puedes ir
>   probando según tus requerimientos.

6.- Para echar a andar tu prueba unitaria, da clic derecho sobre **TestMethod1** y dale en **Ejecutar pruebas** o con el shortcut Ctrl + R, T.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Una pequeña consulta: lo anterior también vale para Visual C++?

Comment: Si, lo haces igual sobre tu solución. Agregar Nuevo Proyecto > Visual C++ > Prueba > Proyecto de Prueba administrado. Consulta  la documentación en MSDN por ejemplo https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/hh598953.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 puedes checar como hacerlo correctamente. Yo solo lo he hecho con Visual Studio para proyectos en C#

Comment: Gracias por responder mi consulta.